# Passing List as Arguments to Command

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file as a list with newlines separating each argument.

```
thing1
thing2
thing3
```

I want to run a command with each item from the list separately so it'd run as

```
do thing1
do thing2
do thing3
```

How would I go about doing this with bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a `while` loop which `read`s the file.

Something like

```sh
while IFS= read -r arg; do
    your_command "$arg"
done < "Your_file"
```

The `<` redirection will send the content of "Your_file" to the while loop, which will read each line, and assign it's value to the `$arg` variable.

Comment: To capture each line verbatim, use `while IFS= read -r line; do ...`

Comment: @glennjackman: Yes, that is indeed better. Thanks. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
  
while read cmd 
do
        do $cmd
done < "args.txt"
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! Solution satisfied everything it needed to